# prevent fiber threads in sweet potato halwa

Tags: pudding, sweet-potatoes

I like sweet potato and i'm trying out different recipes with it as a main ingredient.
One of them is the sweet potato pudding/halwa.
It tastes good, but i would like to get rid of the threads of fibre that keep getting stuck. 
Please suggest how to make the pudding without the threads. 
I remove the ends of the sweet potato to avoid major fibrous part.
And the strings are mainly present in the middle part n not near the skin. The potato near the skin is smooth and doesnt contain strings.

Comment: Your problem has been discussed here before: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17452/any-way-to-make-sweet-mashed-potatoes-less-stringy. The only difference between yours and the recipe in the other question is the spices, so this is a duplicate and will likely be closed. (But hey: we already *have* a solution for you!)

Comment: i see that the description is similar, but the answer is incorrect. The part near the skin is fine, it doesnt have any strings at all. the inner cylinder has lot of fibers. i guess sweet potato in india grows in a different way than the place where Martha is from.

Comment: The answers also discuss that different varieties show a  different "stringyness".

Comment: [This answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/60128/17272) is my preferred method -- beat with an electric mixer for a little while, clean off the strings caught in it, and repeat until there are few or no strings clinging to the beaters. I admit I've never tried with different varieties, though :)

Comment: I am just throwing this in here not knowing if it's appropriate for the recipe, but what about running the uncooked sweet potatoes through a food processor with a grating disk? Wouldn't that cut the fibers short enough that they'll virtually undetectable?

Comment: I think this is still a dup - the accepted answer may not apply to you, but others do. The other *question* isn't specific to sweet potatoes with stringiness near the skin, just the one answer.

Comment: @Escoce If you think that'll work, you might consider posting it on the question there!

Comment: @Jefromi I don't know if it would work, it was just an idea.